# Easiest way to perform a salesforce to salesforce synchronization (one way)?

Tags: migration-tool, automation, migration, data-migration, data-synchronization

We have 2 salesforce organizations. We have a requirement to synchronize changes on data made in the "source" organization to the "target" organization (preferably automatically).

We have quite a few custom objects and many custom fields defined in the standard objects. Some of the custom fields are fields used to define relationships to other objects (can be custom or standard). We need to preserve those relationships.

Preferably we don't want to write any code to do this. We have already manually synchronize 98% of the data using salesforce's Data Loader from the "source" organization to the "target" organization. Before we can migrate our applications to point to the "target" organization, there is still a period when changes are made to the "source" organization and we need to update the same changes in the "target" organization.

What is the easiest solution to do this automatic synchronization between 2 salesforce organizations?

Comment: You can possibly download/replicate the data from SF1 to database using some third party tool &  use the database to restore to SF2 .